# Javascript event parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, discord

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.reply('pong');
  }
});

client.login('your token');
```

**QUESTION:** where is the **message** parameter coming from?

**ELABORATING ON WHAT I MEAN:**

my understanding of arrow functions is that the following snippet from the code above:

```
    message => {
      if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong');
      }
    }
```

is the equivalent of:

```
    function(message){
      if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong');
      }
    }
```

so there is a **message** parameter being inserted into the function when a 'message' is written on one of the servers the discord bot is in. But where is that parameter coming from? No where in the code do I see a message variable being declared and initiated.

Comment: message is coming from the message  event

Comment: most likely a web socked

Comment: its like `$('.x').click(function(e){e.target})`

Comment: oh I see @madalinivascu so the 'message' event carries parameters with it, and depending on the which names I use in the event handler function, those parameters become the names I give it?

Answer (score 0):

The on() method attaches one or more event handlers for the selected elements and child elements, in your case event attached is **Message**.

Therefore, when any user messages, *that* message will serve as parameter to the function.

So as mentioned in comment by Madalin Ivascu, its exactly like $('.x').click(function(e){e.target}) which detects "Click" event of some element.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of events? This is an event handler.
Whenever Discord.js 'sees' a new message, it sends an event to your script with the `message` parameter.

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)'s the discord.js `Client` docs. You can see `message` in "Events" on the right.